# why cracks are observed over time in stainless steel vessels?

Tags: material-science, frequency, applied-physics

We are using stainless steel vessels for long time. But most of the times the vessels made by the stainless steel material are get cracked on its edges. I guessed this would happen due to the coherence of its natural frequency by the environment. Is it correct?

Or else is there any reason behind this cracking occurs?

Comment: I don't see how we can answer this. It could be [stress corrosion cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_corrosion_cracking), as you suggest, but without far more detail how can we say?

Comment: without any stress, if I place it in a closed room which is having no ventilation, the vessels are get cracked in its edges. please explain why it is happening

Comment: Are the edges bended or welded?

Comment: edges are in bend condition

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitting_corrosion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is NOT stress corrosion cracking that just leaves thermal cycling and the resulting stresses in low quality or badly heat treated steel, or simply an annealing process due to, again, badly heat treated steel.